# Calling an function from a dynamically added button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a function `test(instance)` which accept an argument as a test when I click a dynamically added button. However, it throws an error while doing it in the following way. What am I doing wrong here?

```
notificationList.forEach(function(hs) {
        console.log(hs);
        htmlStr = "<tr align='center'>";
            htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.notification + "</td>";
            htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.date + "</td>";
            htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.instance + "</td>";

        htmlStr += "<td  > <input style='align-self: center' type='button' align='center' class='btn btn-primary' value='Info'  onclick='test(hs)'> </input> </td>";
        htmlStr += "</tr>";

        index++;
        $("#hs").append(htmlStr);
    });

function test(instance){
    console.log(instance);
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and follow the guidelines, particularly, learn how to create MCVE.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Can you create a JsFiddle that reproduces the problem so we could more easily help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind an event just after appending the button

```
notificationList.forEach(function(hs) {
    console.log(hs);
    htmlStr = "<tr align='center'>";
        htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.notification + "</td>";
        htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.date + "</td>";
        htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.instance + "</td>";

    htmlStr += "<td>";
    htmlStr += "<input style='align-self: center' type='button' align='center' class='dinamicButton btn btn-primary' value='Info'  onclick='test(hs)'> </input> </td>";
    htmlStr += "</tr>";

    index++;
    $("#hs").append(htmlStr);
    $(".dinamicButton").on("click",test)
});

function test(instance){
  console.log(instance);
}
```

I have added the "dinamicButton" class to your button to make this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery on function. instead of adding `onclick='test(hs)'` you can add this in your javascript:

```
$('btn btn-primary').on('click', function() {
   //your code
})
```

This will be triggered on future elements with the `btn btn-primary` class.

Comment: How does that work, does jQuery constantly watch the DOM for new elements and assign the proper events? Or does it only work if you add them with jQuery?

Comment: I am not sure about the implementation, you can try google it. I believe it check in each insert of a node to the DOM if there is a listener assigned  to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#hs").append(htmlStr).find('input').click(function() {
  test(hs);
});
```

Comment: You call this from inside `notificationList.forEach(function(hs) {`

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving value inside quotes. Try to put value inside quotes and then try.

```js
function addButton(){
  var hs = "button Value";
  
  var buttonText = "<button onclick='test(\"" + hs + "\");'>click here</button>"
  $("#addHere").html(buttonText);
}

addButton();

function test(value){
console.log(value); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addHere"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems:
First, `input` is a self closing tag so:

```
<input ...  onclick='test(hs)' />
```

instead of

```
<input ...  onclick='test(hs)'> </input>
```

Also, in the context of your HTML, `hs` has no meaning... You may want to pass `"hs"` as a string, like so:

```
<input ...  onclick='test("hs")' />
```

and then do whatever you want with that string...

Comment: He tried to get `hs` from `notificationList.forEach(function(hs) {` so `test("hs")` make no sens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
notificationList.forEach(function(hs) {
console.log(hs);
htmlStr = "<tr align='center'>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.notification + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.date + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + hs.instance + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td  > <input style='align-self: center' type='button'    align='center' class='dinamicButton btn btn-primary' value='Info'  onclick='test("hs")'> </input> </td>";
    htmlStr += "</tr>";

index++;
$("#hs").append(htmlStr);
var button=document.getElementsByClassName[0];
button.addEventListener("click", test)
});

function test(instance){
console.log(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Luigonsec solution is correcte exception for line

```
$(".dinamicButton").on("click",test)
```

You could add parameters like this :

```
$(".dinamicButton").on("click",function(){
       test(hs);
});
```